# RoR - dynamic dropdown with checkboxes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox, grouped-collection-select

I am looking to implement a dynamic dropdown with checkboxes in it so the sender of a message can choose multiple receivers.

Currently I just have a list of recipients under the message textarea.

_recipients.html.erb:

```
<% @recipients.each do |user| %>
  <label for="user<%= user.id %>" >
    <span class="list-group-item"><%= user.full_name %></span>
    <%= check_box_tag "message[user_tokens][]", user.id, @message.users.include?(user), id: "user#(user.id)", class: "form-control" %>
  </label>
```

User.rb:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  rolify
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  validates :full_name, presence:true,
            length: {minimum: 4 }

  has_many :messages, foreign_key: :sender_id
  has_many :notes
  has_many :homeworks
  has_many :hw_comments
  belongs_to :classmodule
  belongs_to :student
```

recipient.rb:

```
class Recipient < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :message
    belongs_to :user

    validates :user_id, presence: true
end
```

messages_controller.rb:

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_user!

    def new
        @message = Message.new
        @recipients = User.all 
        @recipients = @recipients.page(params[:page]).per(8)
    end

    def create
        @message = current_user.messages.build(message_params)

        if @message.save
            flash[:success] = "Message sent"
            redirect_to messages_path
        else
            flash[:alert] = "Something went wrong"
            render :new
        end
    end

    def index
        @messages = Recipient.where(:user_id => current_user.id).order('created_at DESC')
    end

    private
    def message_params
        params.require(:message).permit(:title, :body, :sender_id, user_tokens: [])
    end 
end
```

Is it possible to get the checkboxs and names in to a dropdown with collection_select for example? Happy to provide more code if required. Thanks.

Comment: What exactly do you want? Select a list of recipients for a given message?

Comment: Yes, this is what I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using bootstrap you can do this with a dropdown , see example http://www.bootply.com/8V6EpWyMO3

(though you might consider some manual overrides in the js for how sensitive the click is about what is clicked)

For the rails part

If you aren't using simple form and you do want the bootstrap solution you'll need to write a custom input.

Comment: Thanks, link works, I just don't know how to do it in rails. I don't want to hard code in the names. I'd like it dynamic straight from the table.

Comment: are you using simple_form_for or regular form_for -- are you using bootstrap as your css framework?  I can give you details but need to know what you're starting with.

Answer (score 0):

There are different approaches, like using [bootstrap select](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/) with multiple, this way you'd only have one select with the ability to select multiple options. For which you'd have to adapt your `message_params`.

Another approach is using [simple_form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) and [cocoon](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon), as cocoon handle the render of new "views" on associated models. Could be something as simple as having:

(using slim for convenience)

`recipient_fields.slim`

```
.nested-fields
  = f.collection_select :user_id, User.all, :id, :name
  = link_to_remove_association 'remove recipient', f
```

And render a new view each time you want to add a new recipient with:

`link_to_add_association`, handling rendering and destroying html elements by cocoon.

Comment: Thanks for this. What I am looking for preferably us a collection select method that would allow the names and checkboxes to be within the dropdown. Open to other ways of achieving this though.